# How to view documents in App Engine Documents?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-search-api

How can developer view documents in App Engine's Search API on development machine?

I save document using search API and I can search and fetch results using Java API, but how do I view the documents?  Is there a document viewer for development mode?
Details here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/search/

Comment: While I did not find anything for Java 8, you can definetely [view indexes and documents](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/training/fts_intro/lesson3#viewing_indexes_and_documents) using the GCP Console [Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/console/managing-datastore) section, as specified in the Python 2 documentation. You can also access index schemas programatically, as shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/training/fts_intro/lesson3#accessing_index_schemas_programmatically). Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks; App Engine used to provide native web UI to view the documents and after moving to GCloud, I don't see App Engine is providing such UI; looking for such UI to view the documents.

Answer (score 0):

As per **[Google Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/search/#console-indexes):**

> In the Cloud Console, you can **[view information about your application's indexes and the documents they contain](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/search)**. Clicking an index name displays the documents that index contains. You'll see all the defined schema fields for the index; for each document with a field of that name, you'll see the field's value. You can also issue queries on the index data directly from the console.

Comment: As noted in question, I am looking for how does developer view documents in App Engine's Search API on development machine (not on Cloud Console)?

Comment: Just for clarification, you would like to have this same [Search API UI Viewer](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/search) running in your on-premise machine?